# Fiberwise Characteristic Classes

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-topology, characteristic-classes

I recently became interested in a problem of detecting the (non)existence of a section for a bundle where the fibers are not constant.  Let $I$ be the unit interval and let $F_t$, $t \in [0,1]$ be time-varying fibers.  The (standard) picture is this:

$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
\cup_{t \in I} F_t @>>> \cup_{t \in I} I \times F_t\\
& @VVV \\
 && I
\end{CD}
$$

My first thought was to use characteristic classes, so I was wondering if anyone could tell me a little bit about "time-varying characteristic classes" or direct me to an appropriate reference.

Comment: The usual definition of fiber bundle forces the fibers to be homeomorphic (at least over connected bases).  What exactly do you mean by time varying fiber bundle?